# Setting Custom Font for TextView causing the onCreate to take longer to build

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-fonts

I am currently implementing Roboto font within my project. For some fragments, there are a lot of TextView's. I am creating a custom View that exends TextView to implement custom fonts. Is there a better way to load the fonts without increasing the onCreate times?

**Extends TextView**

```
public class TextViewFont extends TextView {

    public TextViewFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public TextViewFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);

    }

    public TextViewFont(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextViewFont);
            String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.TextViewFont_fontName);
            if (fontName != null) {
                Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName);
                setTypeface(myTypeface);
            }
            a.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<com.eugene.fithealthmaingit.Custom.TextViewFont
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dinner"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:fontName="Roboto-Regular.ttf"/>
```

**Example of how many TextView's**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typeface.createfromassets is a time taking process. You should declare typeface as static varaiable in class and just use it in constructor.

But here you are loading fonts in every textview's constructor.

If you having multiple fonts, have all tytypeface as static and use it appropriately.

UPDATE CODE:

```
public class TextViewFont extends TextView {

        public static Typeface typeface1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/fontName1");
        public static Typeface typeface2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/fontName2");
        public static Typeface typeface3 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/fontName3");
        public static Typeface typeface4 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/fontName4");
        public static Typeface typeface5 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/fontName5");

        public TextViewFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            init(attrs);
        }

        public TextViewFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init(attrs);

        }

        public TextViewFont(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init(null);
        }

        private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
            if (attrs != null) {
                TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TextViewFont);
                String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.TextViewFont_fontName);
                if (fontName != null) {
                    setTypeface(getTypeFace(fontName));
                }
                a.recycle();
            }
        }


        public Typeface getTypeFace(String fontName){
            if(fontName.equals("fontName1")){
                return typeface1;
            }else if(fontName.equals("fontName2")){
                return typeface2;
            }else if(fontName.equals("fontName3")){
                return typeface3;
            }else if(fontName.equals("fontName4")){
                return typeface4;
            }else if(fontName.equals("fontName5")){
                return typeface5;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I figured that, I was trying to avoid using it within a class because some TextView's are not declared within the class. Looking for a quick way without declaring all of the TextView's within the class.

Comment: just check my updated answer and hope that would help.

Comment: Ah! I thought you meant within each class. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is the library that saved my life [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy). It's really nice and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an instance singleton or applicationsingleton. See if this works. So you can just call TextLover.get(context).getFont(id). It will create and cache it on the fly. This way your other views can also reuse the font cache. eg. buttons

```
class TextLover {

    private static TextLover singleton;

    private final Context context;

    private final SparseArray<Typeface> faces = new SparseArray<Typeface>();

    public TextLover get(Context context) {
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new TextLover(context);
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    private TextLover(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    private static final String[] fonts = {
        "fonts/fontName1",
        "fonts/fontName2",
        "fonts/fontName3",
        "fonts/fontName4",
        "fonts/fontName5",
            ...
        "fonts/fontName100"
    }

    // NOTE you need a mapping of ids to each asset font in fonts[]

    public Typeface getFont(int id) {
        Typeface font = faces.get(id);
        if (font == null) {
            font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fonts[id]);
            faces.append(id, font);
        }
        return font;
    }

}
```